# JSON child object undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I get stuck on how to display JSON child object.

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 532624048189,
            "title": "Product 1",
            "variants": [
                {
                "id": 6964602208317,
                "price": "100.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 532624277565,
            "title": "Product 2",    
            "variants": [
                {
                "id": 6964602765373,            
                "price": "100.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to display Title but getting undefined value on Variants ID.
Here is my script below.

```
var items = [];
var allItems = [];
var productItems = [];
var filteredVariant = [];
$.getJSON('/collections/all/products.json', {format: "json"})
    .done(function(product) {
    $.each(product.products, function( i, products ) {                     
        productItems.push(products); 
    });
        
    for (var i = 0; i < productItems.length; i++) {
        allItems.push(productItems[i]); 
    }
    $.each(allItems, function( i, item ) {                        
        console.log(items.push('<div><div>'+item.title+'</div><div>'+item.variants.id+'</div>'));
    });                    
});
```

Anybody can assist to fix undefined value on Variants ID?

Comment: variants is an array. You want the first element so it should be `item.variants[0].id`

Comment: or if you have mutliple variants ids you can use each loop again to iterate through them

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGillis, your comment helps a lot